# D3 Voronoi Edge Condition

Tags: d3.js, force-layout, delaunay, voronoi

I'm working with a D3 example file for a [**force directed voronoi graph**](http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning/1734663)... however, I mainly just needed a simplified version with only three vertices... so I simplified the file and have included a [**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/andyopayne/p7geN/) of where my file stands currently.  My issue is how the edge condition is handled.  Right now, the voronoi edges extend out to the edge of the container div.  However, I'd like to clip each voronoi cell by a circle boundary.  I've included two images to help explain my problem. The first image shows the script as it exists now, whereas the second is made with photoshop - showing the circular clipping boundary.  It seems like [**D3's polygon.clip method**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Polygon-Geom#wiki-clip) would be the best option, but I don't really know how to implement the clipping method into my script.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Voronoi without edge boundary][image: Voronoi with circle boundary]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Voronoi Diagram with Force Directed Nodes and Delaunay Links</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      path
        {
            stroke: #EFEDF5;
            stroke-width: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var w = window.innerWidth > 960 ? 960 : (window.innerWidth || 960),
        h = window.innerHeight > 500 ? 500 : (window.innerHeight || 500),
        radius = 5.25,
        links = [],
        simulate = true,
        zoomToAdd = true,
        cc = ["#FFA94A","#F58A3A","#F85A19"]

    var numVertices = (w*h) / 200000;
    var vertices = d3.range(numVertices).map(function(i) {
        angle = radius * (i+10);
        return {x: angle*Math.cos(angle)+(w/2), y: angle*Math.sin(angle)+(h/2)};
    });
    var d3_geom_voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi().x(function(d) { return d.x;}).y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    var prevEventScale = 1;
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function(d,i) {
        if (zoomToAdd){
          if (d3.event.scale > prevEventScale) {
            angle = radius * vertices.length;
          } 
          force.nodes(vertices).start()
        } else {
          if (d3.event.scale > prevEventScale) {
            radius+= .01
          } else {
            radius -= .01
          }
          vertices.forEach(function(d, i) {
            angle = radius * (i+10);
            vertices[i] = {x: angle*Math.cos(angle)+(w/2), y: angle*Math.sin(angle)+(h/2)};
          });
          force.nodes(vertices).start()
        }
        prevEventScale = d3.event.scale;
    });

    d3.select(window)
      .on("keydown", function() {
        // shift
        if(d3.event.keyCode == 16) {
          zoomToAdd = false
        }
      })
      .on("keyup", function() {
        zoomToAdd = true
      })

    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .call(zoom)

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-300)
        .size([w, h])
        .on("tick", update);

    force.nodes(vertices).start();

    var path = svg.selectAll("path");

    function update(e) {
        path = path.data(d3_geom_voronoi(vertices))
        path.enter().append("path")
            // drag node by dragging cell
            .call(d3.behavior.drag()
              .on("drag", function(d, i) {
              vertices[i] = {x: vertices[i].x + d3.event.dx, y: vertices[i].y + d3.event.dy}
          })
        )
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return cc[0] })
    path.attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; })
        .transition().duration(150)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return cc[i] })
    path.exit().remove();

    if(!simulate) force.stop()
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me as if you would want to change the outer path. If you're generating the shape you're looking for to start with and then apply Voronoi, it should work fine.

Comment: This is example is linked to from the D3 wiki page on Voronoi -- looks like what you want: http://bl.ocks.org/njvack/1405439

Comment: More on clipping-paths in SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Comment: Thanks AmeliaBR.  I hadn't seen that example file, but it was helpful.  I've got a clipping circle now, but the center point of the clipping polygon doesn't seem to update with the vertices... which creates some weird behavior.  Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/andyopayne/LRWxx/

Comment: Here's an update: http://jsfiddle.net/uUUF6/.  Now, it looks like one of the clipping polygons is associated with the center voronoi vertice... however, the other two are not.  Any thoughts why?